Is there a good elementary function approximation for the logarithmic integral?
What is an elementary function $f(x)$ such that $|f(x)-\operatorname{li}(x)| < \sqrt{x}$ for sufficiently large $x$?  If one cannot get this small an asymptotic error with not too complicated an elementary function, can one get one giving $|f(x)-\operatorname{li}(x)| < \sqrt{x}\ln{x}$?

There isn't really one. (Otherwise we'd be using that function instead of li$(x)$ whenever we talked about the prime number theorem.)

Maybe take advantage of the logarithmic integral's relationship to $\operatorname{Ei}$ and use Cody and Thacher's Chebyshev approximations for the exponential integral $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$.

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{\log x}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \log x \rfloor}\frac{k!}{\log^k x}$$

The trouble I have with this series approximation is that the number of terms depends on the integer part of log x and so is discontinuous at integer values of log x and hence is not an elementary function.

Notice that instead terminating the sum at a fixed upper bound $m$ yields an $f$ such that $|f(x) - \operatorname{li}(x)| \in O\left(\frac{x}{\log^{m + 1} x}\right)$ for large $x$.

So for large $x$ this has an error much larger than $\sqrt{x}\log{x}$.

@user30463 If you allow the number of terms to be the integer part of $\log x$ then the error is $\mathcal{O}(1)$. At least you have a piecewise elementary function.
